# Event Template Start Date

Tags: civievent, templates, civicrm-event

I created an event template years ago, and when I use this template to create a new event, it auto populates the start date with a very old date. If I edit this event template, the start and end dates aren't shown as something that can be modified.

Where is the auto populated start date coming from and how do I change it? Ideally it would show today's date so that I don't have to scroll through months and years to get to a future date.

We are running CiviCRM 5.8.2 on Drupal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did some testing on mine - it works the same way. It appears that "templates" are actually created and saved just like an actual event. So you'll find the data in the civicrm_event table just like all your other events. It looks like it saves it with a start date that is the same as the date you inputted the template (because date is a required field, but you aren't given the option to input one). The only way I can find thus far to change this is to go into your database, find that template, and edit the date. I just manually changed one of my templates via PHPMyAdmin and sure enough when I go to use it, that date is now the one selected. So at least then you wouldn't need to scroll so far back?

I wonder if someone has an edit they've done to make the date field available when creating a template.

Comment: Taking your advice, I set the start date to Null through PHPMyAdmin and that seems to make new events use the current date rather than a specific date. Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour has changed in more recent versions of CiviCRM to not save the start date in event templates. However, since this does not fix older templates, I submitted a [change request to always ignore the start/end date from templates](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/event/issues/9). Unless it gets blocked, the change should be integrated in CiviCRM 5.17 or 5.18.